# What are the advanvates and disadvantages of vacuum in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, vacuum

I'm new to PostgreSQL, I know about the concept of vacuum in database.

But I want to know the major advantages and disadvantages of vacuuming process.
Also I want to know:

1. What happen if I access the table while vacuuming full database?
2. Whether it will affect the table, or cause data loss?

Comment: re 1. no need to worry, you just access the table re 2. not that will not cause data loss

Comment: Thanks for your reply, It helps to improve my knowledge.

Comment: May I know, what about the major question?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/routine-vacuuming.html and https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Introduction_to_VACUUM,_ANALYZE,_EXPLAIN,_and_COUNT

Answer (score 2):

Vacuum is an inherent part of Postgres due to the MVCC model - you don't have much choice, it's there.

As for `vacuum full` - it rewrites the table and takes an exclusive lock in the process- you won't be able to access your table.

It sounds bad but recent releases reduced the need for `vacuum full` dramatically. 
Frequent regular vacuum (using the autovacuum for example) should be enough in most cases. 
Just make sure to monitor your vacuuming and DB for bloat.